# Django-cms: save_model and api.create_page

Tags: django-cms

I've an external app with a model like this:

```
class Society(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Office(models.Model):
    society = models.ForeignKey(Society)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I need, everytime that an Office is created and saved, autocreate a page with the name of the office.
I was thinking at a def save-model on the Office(models.Model), in whick insert a cms.api create_page, 
but I'm not able to make work it. Anyone could help me?

Comment: Post the save_model code you have, although I think this could also work with signals.

Answer (score 1):

Like this maybe?

```
import cms

parent_page = Page.objects.get(pk=1)   # you will want something more valid than this
approval_user = User.objects.get(pk=1) # again, just selecting the first user, 
                                       # do something better
                                       # like maybe the current request.user?

try:
    page = create_page(title=office.name,
            template=cms.constants.TEMPLATE_INHERITANCE_MAGIC,
            language='en',
            parent=parent_page,
            published=True) # May not want to auto publish?
except Exception, err:
    pass
    # need some handling if the creation fails
```